# init boost::optional of non-copyable object

Tags: boost, default-constructor, noncopyable, boost-optional

What should I do to initialize `boost::optional< T >` if underlying type `T` is non-default constructible, non-copyable/moveable, but one's instance still can exist?

Is it forbidden for `boost::optional` by any semantic reasons to have some member function like `template< typename... Args > boost::optional< T >::construct(Args && ...args)`, that delivers all the arguments to in-place `operator new` to construct the object entirely (for non-ref type `T`)? Variant is to have non-member function like `std::make_shared< T >`.

It seems to me, that my problem can be solved by means of using of `std::unique_ptr`/`std::shared_ptr`, but in this case my question is: "Why `boost::optional` progress is frozen?".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`boost::optional` can be initialized with a non-copyable type by using [in-place factories](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/optional/doc/html/boost_optional/in_place_factories.html).

Specifically, you can use them like this:

```
#include <boost/optional.hpp>
#include <boost/utility/in_place_factory.hpp>

class MyType : private boost::noncopyable
{ 
public:
  MyType(T1 const& arg1, T2 const& arg2);
}
...
boost::optional<MyType> m_var;
...
m_var = boost::in_place(arg1, arg2);
...
```

In C++14 there is a proposed [`std::make_optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/make_optional) that would be a better solution to this problem. However, this has not been implemented in Boost.Optional.

Comment: what if it is default constructible? Is there a way to construct a noncopyable boost::optional without boost::in_place? my various attempts have failed to compile

Comment: If it is a default constructable - call boost::in_place without arguments: Foo foo; foo = boost::in_place();