# Is there a C++14/boost equivalent of std::in_place for `optional`?

Tags: c++, boost

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44989361/can-i-call-optionalemplace-as-a-member-initializer/44989434#44989434) I have an answer to initialize an `optional` with `run( std::in_place, ctor_arg )` to get in-place initialization.  Alas, some of my target platforms appear not to support this yet. Is there a pre-C++17 equivalent using `boost::optional`?

That is, I have an `optional<foo> foo` and wish to initialize it in place in the constructor initialization list:

```
 class outer {
     boost::optional<foo_t> foo;

     outer() : 
        foo{ boost::in_place } // ???
```

*I've attempted `foo{ boost::in_place<foo_t>( foo_t() ) }` based on what I found in the boost docs, but I'm uncertain it's correct. I'm getting a segfault on my constructor relating to the value here and would like to exclude my possibly incorrect optional construction as the cause.*

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16556681/1896169

Comment: `foo{ boost::in_place<foo_t>( foo_t() ) }` definitely should be `foo{ boost::in_place( foo_t() ) }`; don't explicitly spell out template parameters to functions.